# Android ContraintLayout speed when lots of views

Tags: android, android-tablelayout, android-constraintlayout

I have a fragment containing a lot of TextView's and noticed after implementing that opening the fragment took quite some time (seconds) on my Nexus 7 (2013) device.

Is there anyone else having experienced ConstraintLayout being slow with advanced layouts?

I am presenting a table with lots of values. Would choosing a TableLayout be a better option?

XML representation:
https://gist.github.com/ovestoerholt/93d268130fc5e48f2057446c6981d3e3

Had to add link to gist since this textarea does not allow for more than 30000 characters.

Thanks, Ove

Comment: You should use a RecyclerView or another AdapterView to display lists of data.

Comment: @Cheesebaron This is not a list. It's simply a form/screen with lots of info, from the same object, in tabular form.

Comment: Could you add the XML file?

Comment: That layout is going to be relatively slow. A RelativeLayout would have performed better (I think) for this case. The computation cost of the CL algorithms is not free; that being said, perhaps for such a layout, you may want to look into a RecyclerView (as already suggested) and get rid of the NestedScroll.

Comment: use web view instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Martin Marconcini states the algorithms running when 'inflating' a constraintlayout with lots of views is not free, and on my device (the Nexus 7, 2013) it took way too long...

I ended up using a TableLayout, but a combo of LinearLayout and RelativeLayout is probably also a good match.